# SQL : datatype as trunc(sysdate)

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to create a table with a column's data type as `trunc(sysdate)`.
Is that possible?
When I tried it , I got below error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

I am trying this because I want to make sure data inserted into that column doesn't have timestamp.

Comment: See http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/datatypes.php for valid Oracle data types. Maybe one of them will meet your needs. (I would suggest one but I'm not sure what you are asking for.)

Comment: Use a check constraint, `check (column_name = trunc(column_name)`. Datatype is still `date`.

Comment: just store it as a date, and then use a view to format it as you want - at some point you'll be GLAD it's stored as a DATE and not a custom type

Answer (score 2):

Just create a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER schema.trigger_name 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON schema.table_name 
    FOR EACH ROW
        new.column_name = trunc(column_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible.

Trunc() is a function  that truncates  date to a specific unit of measure.

> The DATE datatype stores point-in-time values (dates and times) in a
>   table. The DATE datatype stores the year (including the century), the
>   month, the day, the hours, the minutes, and the seconds (after
>   midnight).